# VSCode TypeScript Auto Import Suggestions - Symbol Resolution Logic

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode with a small TypeScript project that uses several npm packages, including some of my own.  I rely heavily on the Auto Import Suggestions for a fast development flow.

I have noticed that the [VSCode Auto Import Suggestions](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_18#_auto-import-for-javascript-and-typescript) feature will sometimes pick up symbols from npm packages, and sometimes not.  I am trying to identify the logic behind this, but have been unable to figure it out, or find the related code.  I searched the [VSCode sourcecode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode), and found the [settings related to Auto Import Suggestions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/search?q=autoimportsuggestions&unscoped_q=autoimportsuggestions), but then could not find the Auto Import Suggestions code that used this.

So, my questions are:

- **What is the logic behind which symbols show up with Auto Import Suggestions - especially for referenced packages**?
- Where is that code (because, now I just want to look at it!)?
- Is there a way turn on VSCode Debug Logging to see logging statements related to Auto Import Symbol/Module resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto imports should generally always work for npm packages and for local files. If you expect to see a symbol listed in auto imports but it is not there, please [open an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose)

The import logic itself is implemented by the [typescript language server](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/c85460bc44af18df01cc799c2e84010b09a567d4/src/services/completions.ts). It is quite complex and will likely not be helpful to you.

(I maintain VS Code's JS/TS support)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will report an issue if/as I come across examples where this is not working as expected.

Comment: for my reference - how/where can the view the `log()` output from the [typescript language server](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/c85460bc44af18df01cc799c2e84010b09a567d4/src/services/completions.ts) code you referenced?

Comment: in VSCode, set `"typescript.tsserver.trace": "verbose"`. Then you can use the `TypeScript: Open ts server log` command to open the log file. Again, this is probably not going to be useful to you

Comment: Thanks @matt-bierner. At the least, it will satisfy my curiosity.